# Change Dialog Box Text With AppleScript?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, dialog, applescript

Simply, is it possible to change a "static text" field in an Apple system dialog box? Specifically I am looking into changing some label text of a password popup. I have tried using AppleScript via GUI scripting:

```
tell application "System Events"
    try
        tell window 1 of process "loginwindow"
            repeat until not (value of static text 4 is equal to "")
                set value of static text 4 to "this is a test"
                delay 0.5
            end repeat
        end tell
    end try
end tell
```

Although this does not seem to work at all. Any other methods? Perhaps Scripting Bridge or other? I'd prefer not to code my own dialogs from scratch (not for difficulty reasons, I could easily do it, I'd just prefer to interface rather than emulate.)

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do by hacking loginwindow's dialog boxes in this way?

Comment: just to slightly modify the instruction given after a bad password is entered. Static text 4 is the "Incorrect Password or Username" field, I want to modify it to say something like "Incorrect Password, 10 seconds before logout" which is a function my program executes behind the login window.

Comment: are you talking about the main login window ?

Comment: no - the screensaver login dialog box. It has the title of "loginwindow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I'm not sure that this is possible - it would be best to write a screen saver, implement it's own password protection, and enable that dialog to be modified from behind the screen saver.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea... I don't think you can change the login window text itself but you can change the background picture of the login window. Therefore you may be able to setup some images, and then use those images during the login process to display what you want.

I never tried it but this post shows how to do this... [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070610164328933).

Comment: This is a temporary solution, but not ideal. Does anyone have any ideas regarding the original problem?